# Ionic google map is not loading on ios but working on browser

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am trying to load google map in ionic app environment. It works on perfectly on browser. But, I can only see my tabs with a blank screen in the place of map when I load the app on to iphone and simulator. I tried with both google browser api key and also with ios key. Please help me. 
Here is my controller and html.

controller:

```
  angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

 .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading ) {
  var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function (position) {

  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

  var mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  //Wait until the map is loaded
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function () {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: $scope.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "Here I am!"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
    });

  });

}, function (error) {
  console.log("Could not get location");
});

//center function
$scope.centerOnMe = function () {
  console.log("Centering");
  if (!$scope.map) {
    return;
  }

  $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Getting current location...',
    template: '<ion-spinner class="spinner-energized"></ion-spinner>',
    showBackdrop: false
  });

  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function (position) {

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };
    $scope.loading.hide();

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  });
}
})
```

here is my HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="mymap">
<ion-content>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" data-tap-disabled="true">                 </div>
```

Comment: did you mean objective c, swift or IOS device safari browser , please be specific

Comment: it is in Safari browser